# Is Object.prototype.toString a function or a property?

Tags: javascript

Before asking, I have tried to do my homework and to avoid a duplicate. Thus, I have read about 20 questions and answers (mainly on SO) which all deal with toString(). But unfortunately, none of them did answer my actual question. So here we go ...

Many examples contain code like that:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(someVariable);
```

I just would like to know why `toString` can be used like a property here. I have read the reference for `Object.prototype` at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) and other places. All of them list **a function** `toString()` among the members of `Object.prototype`, but **no property** `toString`.

Furthermore, I am using a line like that shown above at several places in my code. For testing purposes, I have added parentheses to make it "clean":

```
Object.prototype.toString().call(someVariable);
```

Obviously, that did not make it "clean", but just made it return wrong results or even made the browser stall (I am currently in the process of researching what exactly is going on).

I already have read some questions and answers regarding calling functions without parentheses. But even if I accept that the first of the code lines shown above actually calls a function (although it looks like accessing a property), that still does not explain why it goes wrong horribly when I add the parentheses as shown in the second code line. Being able to call functions without parentheses should not mean being unable to call them with parentheses, should it?

I don't think that question has an answer already (if yes, I apologize), so could anybody please give a short explanation?

Comment: `Object.prototype` is another ordinary object and `toString` is a property of it with a function assigned as value. Just like `{sayHello: function(){console.log("hello")}`

Comment: typeof Object.prototype.toString

Comment: It sounds like you have some background knowledge in some other language (like Scala) based on your assumptions. Am I correct?

Comment: @TamasHegedus Yes, I have background in several other languages (C, assembly, vb.net, C#, Perl and so on, but never heard of Scala).

Comment: To all who commented and helped so far: Thank you very much! I know the concept of function references (and that references are values / properties; in fact, I am using this at many place in my code). What me completely worried is that all references I have seen list `Object.prototype.toString()` in the section **methods** and **not** in the section **properties**.

Comment: A "method" is just a property whose value is a function (reference). This is an artifact of how documentation is organized, not really a language issue.

Comment: @melpomene I see. From my point of view, *that* is the actual answer to my worries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions are just values. `toString` is a property of the `Object.prototype` object whose value is a function.

`()` is the function call operator. `Object.prototype.toString` doesn't call a function; it just fetches the value of the `Object.prototype.toString` property (which happens to be a function).

Functions are also objects, with properties of their own. That's why you can do `Object.prototype.toString.call(...)`: This gets the `Object.prototype.toString` function, then fetches its `call` property, then calls it (which is allowed because the value of `call` is another function).

This works even without involving properties:

```js
var foo = function () { return "hello"; };
var bar = foo;
console.log(bar);
console.log(bar());
```

The first line assigns a function value to the `foo` variable.

The second line assigns the same value to `bar`, reading from `foo`. Note that we're not calling the function, we're just passing it around like any other value.

The first `console.log` displays the function itself.

The second `console.log` displays the result of calling the function, because we used `()`.

Comment: Re our discussion the other day about objects being values, I thought you'd be interested in these two threads on the topic from the es-discuss mailing list: https://esdiscuss.org/topic/are-objects-values and https://esdiscuss.org/topic/are-the-values-of-objects-the-references-to-them. Essentially, as far as I can tell, we were both right. :-) Thank you again for challenging my assumptions on this, was a learning exercise.

Answer (score 3):

> Is Object.prototype.toString a function or a property?

`Object.prototype.toString` is a property. The *value* of that property is a reference to a function. Exactly like this:

```
var obj = {f: function() { } };
```

There, `obj.f` is a property, the value of which is a reference to a function.

The **initial** value of `Object.prototype.toString` is the intrinsic function known in [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-object.prototype.tostring) as `%ObjProto_toString%`. It can be overwritten, but doing so would like break a lot of things.

---

The thing to remember is that in JavaScript, functions are just objects that inherit from `Function.prototype`* and are callable. Just like other objects, you can keep references to them in properties and variables (you can even add properties to functions themselves), pass those references around, etc. This is in marked contrast to many languages which treat "classes" and methods and other kinds of functions as special, non-object things.

---

* *(host-provided objects aren't required to inherit from `Function.prototype`, but in modern environments most do; in some obsolete browsers, some don't.)*

Comment: Thanks for helping out and +1. I'll accept melpomene's answer because he explained the complete chain up to the final `.call(...)`, and he needs more points :-), and he made a very valuable comment to my question (the main source of my worries was that `toString()` is listed in the section "methods" and not the section "properties" in all references I saw), and he explained why.

Comment: @Binarus: Always accept the answer you found most helpful, and don't worry about someone being cross you didn't accept theirs. That's *their* problem, not yours. :-) I'm just happy if you found the above helpful as well.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to JavaScript. It's true that functions can be called without `()` in some cases (specifically, `new f`), but not in this case. What you see is the reference to the function being used as an object but *not called* (yet). That's a common thing to do, although in this case it's probably a bit more obscure than usual so I'll explain *why* it's done like that.

The function finally gets called when you explicitly call its `call` method (every function inherits that from the Function prototype), which allows you to bind `this` in the function body to some arbitrary object. Your first example *may* do the same thing as `someVariable.toString()`. So why use the longer form ?

Well, someVariable may not have a `toString` method (if it's null or undefined, because they are not objects and can't be boxed into an object), in which case using `someVariable.toString` would throw a TypeError. Or its prototypal `toString` method may have a different behaviour than the one for basic Objects. In this case, I guess that the author wanted to use an old-school trick for getting the name of an object's "species", which involves the fact that `Object.prototype.toString` always returns `"[Object whatever]"` where "whatever" will be the constructor's name or Null or Undefined.

Comment: Thanks for helping. Here is a good article about `.call()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call My main problem was that `toString()` is in the section "methods" and not in the section "properties" in all references I have seen. But melpomene has made a comment to my original question (in addition to his answer) and explained why.

Comment: You're welcome. I know I wasn't exactly answering your question, but others did that quicker than me. I though you might still wonder why `call` was used at all so I posted anyway.